# MySQL connection failed between 2 pods in kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am a newbie on Kubernetes and try to generate 2 pods including front-end application and back-end mysql. First I make a yaml file which contains both application and mysql server like below,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: blog-system
spec:
  containers:
  - name: blog-app
    image: blog-app:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Never 
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
    args: ["-t", "-i"]
    link: blog-mysql
  - name: blog-mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    env:
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        value: password
      - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        value: password
      - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
        value: test
    ports:
      - containerPort: 3306
```

The mysql jdbc url of front-end application is `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test`. And pod generation is successful. The application and mysql are connected without errors. And this time I seperate application pod and mysql pod into 2 yaml files.

== pod-app.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: blog-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: blog-mysql
  containers:
  - name: blog-app
    image: app:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
    args: ["-t", "-i"]
    link: blog-mysql
```

== pod-db.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: blog-mysql
  labels: 
    app: blog-mysql
spec:
  containers:
  - name: blog-mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    env:
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        value: password
      - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        value: password
      - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
        value: test
    ports:
      - containerPort: 3306
```

But the front-end application can not connect to mysql pod. It throws the connection exceptions. I am afraid the mysql jdbc url has some incorrect values or the yaml value has inappropriate values. I hope any advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the working case since same pod has two containers they are able to talk using localhost but in the second case since you have two pods you can not use localhost anymore. In this case you need to use the pod IP of the mysql pod in the frontend application. But problem with using POD IP is that it may change. Better is to expose mysql pod as [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and use service name instead of IP in the frontend application. Check this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/)

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to write service for exposing the db pod.
There are 4 types of services.

1. `ClusterIP`
2. `NodePort`
3. `LoadBalancer`
4. `ExternalName`

Now you need only inside the cluster then use `ClusterIP`
For reference use following yaml file.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: mysql-svc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: blog-mysql
```

Now you will be access this pod using `mysql-svc:3306`
Refer this in blog-app yaml with

```
    env:
      - name: MYSQL_URL
        value: mysql-svc
      - name: MYSQL_PORT
        value: 3306
```

For more info use Url :https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Answer (score 0):

Pods created will have dns configured in the following manner

`pod_name.namespace.svc.cluster.local`

In your case assuming these pods are in default namespace your jdbc connection string will be

`jdbc:mysql://blog-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local:3306/test`

Refer: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods

Like Arghya Sadhu and Sachin Arote suggested you can always create a service and deployment. Service and deployment helps you in the cases where you have more than one replicas of pods and service takes care of the load-balancing.